# Does there exist a point $x \in A$ such that $|x-12| =0.0012$?

Tags: real-analysis

$12$ is  an interior point  of  $A$  where  $A $ is  a  subset of $\mathbb{R}$
Now  Question is that

Is there exist a  point $x  \in  A$  such that  $|x-12| =0.0012$?

My attempt : yes, because  $A$  contain an interval   as neighbourhood  point must contain   inside the interval

Is its true?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Is there any further information about A?

Comment: @user376343 $A$ be  subset  of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $12$  is an interior point of $A$

Comment: Then is your proof wrong - the idea is good, but an interval containing 12 can be shorter than 0.0012

Comment: @user376343 oh  ya  i missed that logics

Comment: "because A contain an interval as neighbourhood point must contain inside the interval" But there's no reason that interval needs to be as large as $.0012$.  Take $A = (11.99999999999999999, 12.00000000000000001)$ then if $x \in A$ then $|x - 12| < 0.0000000000000002 < 0.0012$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously not; consider for example the interval $A=(11.9988,12.0012)\subset\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: thanks u @Servaes